# Al introducir valores mediante punteros me sale 1.#INF00

Tags: c

> Realiza un programa que calcule la intensidad que circula por una resistencia dados
> R y V. I=V/R suponiendo que la función main del programa sea:
>
> ```
> int main()
> {
>     float res, vol, intensidad;
>     obtener_valores(&res,&vol);
>     intensidad= calcular(res, vol);
>     imprimir_respuesta(intensidad);\
> }
> ```

Este es mí código:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void obtener_valores(float *pot,float *ohm);
float calcular(float pot,float ohm);
void imprimir_respuesta(float amp);

int main(){
    float res,vol,intensidad;
    
    obtener_valores(&res,&vol);
    intensidad =  calcular(res,vol);
    imprimir_respuesta(intensidad);
    
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void obtener_valores(float *pot,float *ohm){
    printf("Introduce los valores: ");
    scanf("%f %f",&pot, &ohm);
}

float calcular(float pot,float ohm){
    float amp;
    amp = pot / ohm;
    return amp;
}

void imprimir_respuesta(float amp){
    
    printf("El valor de la intensidad es: %f\n",amp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

En la función `main` ya estás pasando las direcciones de las variables. El operador `&` significa *obtener dirección*.

```
obtener_valores(&res, &vol);
```

En la otra función, `float* pot` y `float* ohm` son punteros y ya poseen las direcciones. Así que solo debes darle una copia a `scanf`:

```
void obtener_valores(float *pot, float *ohm){
    printf("Introduce los valores: ");
    scanf("%f %f", pot, ohm);
}
```

`pot` y `ohm` así como cualquier puntero son variables. Lo único que los diferencia de las variables normales es que todos almacenan una dirección de memoria, y puedes leer y escribir a dicha dirección de memoria.

Por lo tanto, estarías tomando la dirección de memoria de `float* pot` y `float* ohm`. De esta manera los valores de las variables que viven en la función `main` no son alterados; por cierto no están inicializadas, tienen basura y por eso obtienes resultados extraños.